# Django ModelForm for MultiTableInheritance

Tags: django, inheritance, modelform

So I have a model heirarchy using multi-table inheritance and I was wondering if there was a some sort of ModelForm or similar approach for creating an object like a normal model form and have the user choose which of the subclasses they want to use in the form in like a choice field.

The heirarchy is as follow:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
class A(Base):
    pass
class B(Base):
    pass
class C(Base):
    pass
```

I can't use Meta abstract models because I have one class that needs a foreign key to the Base which is why I'm using multi-table inheritance and in the future the child classes may have additional field. Do you have any suggestions of how I go about doing this?

Currently the way I'm doing it is using a normal form and having all the common fields in that form as well as a choice field which they can select the type of the model they want to use and then I've created a save method which interprets the type from the choice field and creates the object of that type. I can't help but feel there is a better method of doing this.

Comment: Couldn't you use the ContentTypes framework for the foreign key, to solve your abstract model problem in the first place? I believe it would save you from many problems.

Comment: Um, well these classes all share a fair number of fields and there are also instances where I'd like to display them all together using the base class that they inherit from.